# My code is not displaying phone value

Tags: lightning-web-components

My output is[image: Account List]

It displays a Phone column but no value in it

**HTML Code**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Account List">
        <lightning-layout>
            <lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-input label="Number of Records" onchange={recordLimitHandler}></lightning-input> 
    </lightning-layout-item>
</lightning-layout>
<div if:true={accounts}>
            <lightning-datatable key-field="id"
            data={accounts}
            columns={columns}></lightning-datatable>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**.js**

```
import { LightningElement,track } from 'lwc';
import getAllAccount from '@salesforce/apex/AccountList.getAccount';

const columns = [{
    label : 'Name',
    fieldName : 'Name',
    type : 'url',
    typeAttributes : {label : {fieldName : 'Name'}, target:'_blank'}},
    { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'phone', type: 'phone' },
] ;

export default class AccountList extends LightningElement {
    @track columns = columns;
    @track searchRecord;
    @track accounts;
recordLimitHandler(event)
    {
        this.searchRecord = event.target.value;
        getAllAccount({strSearchName : this.searchRecord}).then(response =>
            {
                this.accounts = response;
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log('There is an issue in loading the account');
            })
    }
}
```

**Apex class**

```
public with sharing class AccountList {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Account> getAccount(String strSearchName){
       String searchName = '%'+strSearchName+'%';
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Phone FROM Account where Name LIKE  :searchName];        
    }
}
```

Please let me know what's wrong in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is *case-sensitive*. The property name is `Phone`, not `phone`.